# Installing Python3 on Centos7 Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-3.x, centos, raspberry-pi, yum

I am having trouble installing python3 on centos7 on my pi.
I got my build of centos from here:
https://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/AltArch/Arm32/RaspberryPi3

and it seems I can't install the right repositories to get python3 with yum.  I tried all the tutorials online, and none of them work.  Any ideas how to do this on the pi?

Comment: What error do you get? what repos are you trying to add...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually install python 3.4 without any problem.

At the terminal, enter:

```
cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo << EOF
```

then put in the following lines:

```
[epel]
name=Epel rebuild for armhfp
baseurl=https://armv7.dev.centos.org/repodir/epel-pass-1/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0

EOF
```

then, you need to install epel-release which contains python34:

```
yum install epel-release
```

after that, you are ready to install Python 3.4.

```
yum install python34
```

to get the pip,

```
yum install python34-pip
```

Comment: This works for me, don't know thought why we change the epel.repo because we later get a warning "warning: /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo created as /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo.rpmnew" Most likely because I have a lack of knowledge in the repo area =)